# OpenWRT - route all the traffic through TOR

Tags: openwrt, tor

Passing through all the traffic in the router to TOR sounds like a good idea.

But there aren't any good documentations about the implementation of this idea.

Could anyone please explain, how can someone, that has an OpenWRT flashed, example cheap router (with Gbit links and N wifi and USB): TL-WR1043ND configure it to route all the traffic that goes through it via TOR?

So if a user connects via cable or wifi to the router, all the traffic would be automagically routed to TOR network, without any client-side configuration.

The setup could be used in internet cafee's or wherever "free" internet is need to be deployed, and we don't want to face the legal consequences of what our wireless clients did on the internet..

Comment: There is a howto at openwrt forums : https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=27354 .Have your tried?